# JMS delivery order in EMS or BW

Tags: jms, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

Is there any way you can control the order delivery of messages in a topic in EMS or Tibco (using a JMS Topic Subscriber)? Something like the message selector, but instead of filtering to do ordering.

I would like to use a header like JMSXDeliveryCount, so that new messages will get a higher priority. I know that there's RedeliveryDelay, but that works only for queues, not topics.

Even JMSPriority could be an option if I can set it after getting the message with a topic subscriber. Can I do that? Maybe with a Java Code activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMSPriority is indeed an option, but it cannot be set on an already received message. The solution is to confirm the message and republished it with a different priority.

Answer (score 0):

The broker will deliver messages in order as it receives them, but re-ordering messages is a distributed computing / EIP problem (see sequencer). The issue is the broker does't know how many messages are coming or how long to keep the window open for re-ordering messages. This activity is best done outside the broker in your application where that information is understood.

EIP frameworks and ESB's have done a nice job of standardizing a handler for this type of workflow.

ref: EIP Sequencer http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageSequence.html

Comment: My question is about EMS not Camel.

Comment: Right.. I was just using Camel's documentation and syntax to illustrate the logic / algorithm.  Any EIP or integration framework can perform the function. The point is.. don't rely on the broker to do it.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the references to Camel's resequencer example

Comment: Actually JMSPriority is already used to order messages. And if a message with a higher priority comes in it will be redelivered first, without any concern about future messages. My problem is if I can set this for messages redelivered.